# 4 equations system with too many unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

$$x{b^3} = w{b^3} + y$$
$$px{b}^3 = rw{b^3} - 2ry$$
$$w{a^3} + y = -t{a^3} + z$$
$$rw{a^3} - 2y = -qt{a^3} - 2qz$$

I need to find $x,y,w,z$ as a function of $p,q,r,a,b$ and $t$.

Comment: Could you give us some context? How did you come across this problem? What have you tried? Do you have any tools or techniques that you think might be useful here?

Comment: Please show your efforts in solving this question, this is very important on Math SE. You must show your efforts.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** We can rewrite the system as
$$
\pmatrix{-b^3 & b^3 & 1 & 0\\
-rb^3 & rb^3 & 2r & 0\\
a^3 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
ra^3 & 0 & -2 & 2q} \pmatrix{w\\x\\y\\z} = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0\\ -ta^3 \\ -qta^3}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$
x=\frac{ - 9a^3qrt}{2a^3pq + a^3pr + 4a^3qr + 2a^3r^2 - 2b^3pq + 2b^
3p + 2b^3qr - 2b^3r},
$$

$$
y=\frac{3a^3b^3qt(p - r)}{2a^3pq + a^3pr + 4a^3qr + 2a^3r^2 - 2b^3pq + 2b^
3p + 2b^3qr - 2b^3r}
$$

and similar formulas for $z,w$. This follows by using elimination.